# Remove declared body background image (ie conditional)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to have a separate CSS stylesheet for old Explorer browsers

How can I change what is previously asigned to the BODY tag? I want to remove the background image, using css only

I have tried redeclaring the body. That did not do it
Then I tried adding a class

background-image: none
or
background-image: none !important

Didn't help either. Maybe I'm too tired..

Comment: Are you sure that your conditional css file is being loaded?

Comment: Should I just try with: body { background-image: none !important } ?

Comment: How are you including the second IE only stylesheet? Through conditional comments or another way? As @sdsanders suggested the stylesheet not being loaded is most probably your problem.

Comment: It was the css markup itself that was the problem.. I was using "html, body" on the main sheet.. and so re-setting "body" again did nothing.. Now I have changed it to only body, and tested in the main css file without ie-sheet. I guess "body { }" is the same as "html, body { }"?

Comment: Hmm.. actually I need "html, body" for my layout.. but no problem, I just reset that in the oldie.css file